# Is there any Checkinstall alternative since its too old?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling

I wonder if there is a better and newer Checkinstall alternative for Ubuntu. Its latest version 1.6.2 released [Dec 26th, 2009](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/news.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkinstall is up-to-date.

The correct link is http://checkinstall.izto.org/ with **Recent news
from Dec 30th, 2016** and it is shown on https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/checkinstall :

> [image: link]

[image: Checkinstall]

> ```
> $ apt-cache show checkinstall | grep Homepage
> Homepage: http://checkinstall.izto.org
> ```

And git repository is also fresh:

> ```
> $ git clone http://checkinstall.izto.org/checkinstall.git
> $ cd checkinstall/
> $ git log | head -n3
> commit d24a630501a9aba5d53de2dcb3d9aa66edd3fe06
> Author: Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran <antispam>
> Date:   Wed Apr 26 17:37:50 2017 -0500
> ```