# Best practice for managing packages installed from source

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, uninstall, source-packages

What's the best practice for installing/upgrading/uninstalling packages that are compiled from source? How do I keep track of all installed files and upgrade/remove them as necessary without littering all over the place. I'm running 18.04 LTS.

I looked into `checkinstall`, but [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138405/283449) suggests it's not recommended due to security risks and the package seems lack of maintenance too.

Comment: Keep a calendar and good compile/install notes. You seem to be describing the maintenance nightmare that led to the original development of software packages and package manager and distros 20 years ago.